# Content assist not working on Eclipse 2023-09

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-22.04, content-assist

When I booted up Ubuntu 22.04 it worked, but autocompletion in Eclipse 2023-09 has disappeared. Whenever I try to autocomplete with Ctrl + Space or try to access a method from an object with ".", nothing shows up. Also, when trying to fix an error via the Quick Fix shortcut (Ctrl + 1), nothing happens either (I have to go to the "Problems" tab and right click the error to be able to quick-fix it. Hovering over warnings or errors in the text editor displays an empty box.

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation is enabled. Proposal Kinds in Advanced are also checked. No solution after restarting the IDE, reinstalling it or rebooting the system.

EDIT 10/18/2023: Ctrl + Space is already key-bound in dialogs and windows, but when trying add to add the binding in the General -> Keys section as @howlger suggested, the combination's not recognised. Something in the system is catching the combination, but I can't understand what.

Comment: In the preferences _General > Keys_, is the command _Content Assist_ bound to Ctrl+Space? In the same preference page, set the focus into the _Binding_ field and hit Ctrl+Space. If Ctrl+Space is not displayed, Ctrl+Space is caught by something else so Eclipse does not get it.

Comment: It is indeed set to Ctrl + Space, I forgot to mention in the OP

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77308139/edit) your question to add this information. It is very likely (at least it was once for me) that something is catching Ctrl+Space so Eclipse does not get it. To verify whether this is the cause, go to the preferences _General > Keys_, set the focus into the Binding field and hit Ctrl+Space. If Ctrl+Space is not displayed, Ctrl+Space is caught by something else.

Comment: So maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/243639)?

Comment: Glad to hear that you have found the solution yourself. Please turn your "EDIT 2" into a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Looks like the keyboard I connected the laptop to was the responsible of the confusion. I just unplugged it and it works fine. Thanks everybody